# ht-access how to redirect to a forum topic url?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to know how to use ht-access to redirect my pages which look as follows .com/?page=forums&topic=topic-name to be changed to .com/forums/topic-name?

The rule below redirects all the page names for example .com/forums or .com/polls which i currently use to get my pages to .com/index.php?page=forums.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

i would like [www.treyarder.com/home](http://www.treyarder.com/home) to redirect to [www.treyarder.com/index.php?page=home](http://www.treyarder.com/index.php?page=home) as well as [www.treyarder.com/forums/topic-name](http://www.treyarder.com/forums/topic-name) to redirect to [www.treyarder.com/index.php?page=forums&topic=topic-name](http://www.treyarder.com/index.php?page=forums&topic=topic-name)

my topic is at [www.treyarder.com/index.php?page=forums&topic=topic-name](http://www.treyarder.com/index.php?page=forums&topic=topic-name)

my ht-access file as shown below

```
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=%1&topic=%2 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?pages=404
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php?pages=500
```

there seems to be something wrong with the below line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ [NC]
```

does anyone know what it may be? as if i can fix that line then this should hopefully solve my question.

Comment: So you mean user will hit URL like `http://localhost.singh.com/forums/topic-name` and it will be served by `http://localhost.singh.com/?page=forums&topic=topic-name`? Please confirm this once.

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Please don't update your htaccess file from answer, that will confuse everyone, please revert your changes to your original post.

Comment: i do apologies, i must of changed the current code rather than add more code

Comment: /forums/ is a page which redirects to a $_GET["page"] variable which is received with PHP and is displayed as www.treyarder.com/index.php?page=forums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove both `ErrorDocument` lines from your .htaccess as you're handling all non-file, non-dir requests through your front controller pattern.

You may try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&topic=$2 [L,QSA]

## COMMENT OUT THESE 2 LINES
# ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?pages=404
# ErrorDocument 500 /index.php?pages=500
```

**css/js/images issue:** It is due to your use of relative links for these resources.  Try **ANY** of these 2 work-arounds:

1. Use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`
2. Add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: great www.treyarder.com/forums/topic-name now works, how can i also get www.treyarder.com/home to work like it did before, never mind found a work arround simply by doing /home/

Comment: First rule is there to take care of `/home`

Answer (score 0):

okay this was the final outcome which we managed to mix and match until it worked.

```
RewriteEngine on  

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=%1&topic=%2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]*)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=%1 [L]
```