# I want to remove forum from url/forum/topic

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I will like to change url/forum/topic to url/topic

I want the forum to be removed.. Any rewrite please..

I have this on htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^forum/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)$  category.php?url=$1&pn=$2 [L] # process user profile
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ category.php?url=$1 [L] # process category

RewriteRule ^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ categoryPagination.php?url=$1&link=$2  [L] # process category

#RewriteRule ^forum/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$  categoryPagination.php?url=$1&link=$2 [L] # process user profile

RewriteRule ^links/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ pages.php?link=$1 [L] # process user profile

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)$  board.php?url=$1&pn=$2 [L] # process user profile

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ board.php?url=$1 [NC,L] # Process board

RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+).html$ readtopic.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L] # Process blog topic

RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ readpost.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L] # Process blog posts

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z]+)$ userposts.php?user=$1&type=$2 [L] # Process blog posts

#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ category.php?title=$1&id=$2 [NC,L] # Process blog posts
```

And i have something like this in some files

```
<span class="tags"><a href="forum/<?php echo $dsurl; ?>"><?php echo $dsname; ?></a></span>
```

And

```
$url="forum/".$url;

<a href="'.WEBROOT.'/forum/'.$slink.'">
```

etc.

I will like to change https://espbase.com/forum/games to https://espbase.com/games

I come across this on stackoverflow: [can i use this and does it need any changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65539405/ht-access-how-to-redirect-to-a-forum-topic-url)

Comment: Please do add your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Kindly do some research by "searching" on Stackoverflow itself Or Google it and then add your efforts in your question. Adding efforts by Original poster is very much encouraged on Stackoverflow here, thank you.

Comment: Have edited the question... I found something on my htaccess

Comment: Great and Thanks a lot for adding your efforts(there is nothing wrong or right here), could you please add more meaningful URLs eg: `http://localhost:80/etc_etc` in form of FROM which url TO which url you want to rewrite/redirect, that will give better picture of your question, thank you.